# Cleanup job for CDC failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, change-data-capture

The clean up job for CDC failed with this error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

If this error occurs in other case, then it was normal. But a system procedure is not usual I think.

What should I check first? The same error happens when I run this manually:

```
sys.sp_MScdc_cleanup_job
```

Comment: Weird. Any information in the SQL Logs?